# MPI_Pack vs MPI_Create_struct

Tags: c, struct, dynamic, mpi

Its not that I am stuck but more of a "What do you think best" type of question.
I have an array of structs that I want to send to the second proccess but each struct has a dynamical allocated array ( it has int,int and *int).
So if I create MPI_Create_struct then I need to create each struct separatly and send it separatly, because each struct has a different size of array inside so is different in size from other structs .
Same goes if I pack the content of structs : each struct will be packed and sent separatly because each array size is different and so the struct size i send is different.
Is there a way to send the structs in one take or whould I just send the structs one by one , each with its size??
Thank you for the answers .

Comment: does the receiver know the size of all the struct before receiving the message? if not, you need to figure out a way to allocate space (either for the data, or the packed buffer). packing is likely easier, but at the expense of requiring twice the memory. Also, if your program is MPI+OpenMP, packing/unpacking the data with OpenMP is likely faster than using adhoc derived datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `int*` in your struct can not be sent anyway as part of a struct, because it's not contiguous with the other two items. I'd say: pack them. It's easy enough to make a packed message "self-documenting": you enclose the size information in the message.

Comment: Didnt want to start packing many structs in a loop , but in the end your solution was the one that I prefered as well. Thank you for your help and the time that you invested in my little problem.